# How to access test suite properties when using record_testsuite_property fixture in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

According to the Pytest documentation, we can use the `record_testsuite_property` fixture to record properties specific to the test suite.

So I'm using that fixture like this:

```
import pytest

class TestSuite:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def init(self, record_testsuite_property):
        record_testsuite_property("suite_name", "Test Suite #1")

    def test_example(self, record_property):
        record_property('test_id', 'ABC-123')
        record_property('test_name', 'Example Test #1')
        assert True
```

I would like to access the value of `suite_name` when I am generating the report like so:

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    
    if item.user_properties:
        test_properties = { prop[0]: prop[1] for prop in item.user_properties }

        # These are added via `record_property` fixture and I am able to access them with no issue.
        report.test_id = test_properties["test_id"]
        report.test_name = test_properties["test_name"]

        # Not able to get the suite_name from here.
        # report.suite_name = test_properties["suite_name"]

        setattr(report, "duration_formatter", "%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

The whole idea is that I want to have `suite_name` be a property that is attached to each item so that I can include it in the report.

So I realized that I would still use the `record_property` fixture here and have it automatically requested (using `autouse=True`) at the `function` scope.

```
import pytest

class TestSuite:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
    def init(self, record_property):
        record_property("suite_name", "Test Suite #1")

    def test_example(self, record_property):
        record_property('test_id', 'ABC-123')
        record_property('test_name', 'Example Test #1')
        assert True
```

And now I can access `suite_name` here:

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    
    if item.user_properties:
        test_properties = { prop[0]: prop[1] for prop in item.user_properties }

        report.test_id = test_properties["test_id"]
        report.test_name = test_properties["test_name"]
        report.suite_name = test_properties["suite_name"]

        setattr(report, "duration_formatter", "%M:%S")
```